# Collider does not works properly in RealityKit

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I have a `.rcproject` file with a goal (football gate) and a ball, the ball has physics of Dynamic and Rubber material, and the goal is Fixed with Lead material. When I load the scene from the `.rcproject` file, I set the goal collider to be the exact mesh of the tubes that make the goal's frame and the net, using `generateConvex` of the `model.mesh`.

But, it seems like the ball is touching the goal, and it collides with some invisible wall that is at the "entrance" of the goal, kinda like it's just a 2d wall, instead of the ball actually going inside the goal like it would in real life.
This is my code:

```
Experience.loadSceneAsync { result in
    switch result {
        case let .success(scene):
            guard let tubeOneGeometry = scene.findEntity(named: "Tube_Red_0")?.children[0] as? ModelEntity,
                  let tubeTwoGeometry = scene.findEntity(named: "Tube_White_0")?.children[0] as? ModelEntity,
                  let netGeometry = scene.findEntity(named: "Net_Net_0")?.children[0] as? ModelEntity,
                  let tubeOneMesh = tubeOneGeometry.model?.mesh,
                  let tubeTwoMesh = tubeTwoGeometry.model?.mesh,
                  let netMesh = netGeometry.model?.mesh,
                  let goal = scene.goal 
            else { return }

            let tubeOneShape = ShapeResource.generateConvex(from: tubeOneMesh)
            let tubeTwoShape = ShapeResource.generateConvex(from: tubeTwoMesh)
            let netShape = ShapeResource.generateConvex(from: netMesh)
            goal.components[CollisionComponent.self] = CollisionComponent(
                            shapes: [tubeOneShape, tubeTwoShape, netShape])    
            arView.debugOptions.insert(.showPhysics)

            let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)
            anchor.addChild(scene)
            arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)

        case let .failure(error):
            print("Failed to load scene: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andy Jazz Sure, https://dropmefiles.com/pvRav (Its the first scene called Soccer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Low-rez Collision Shape

You forgot to turn  the default collision shape for the football gate OFF. Also, the [generateConvex(from:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/shaperesource/generateconvex(from:)-53jm9) method built an irregularly shaped collision shape. Use the following code to generate robust collision shape programmatically (however, a good practice is to create a low-resolution collision shape in 3D authoring apps like Autodesk Maya):

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                        
        Experience.loadSoccerAsync { result in
            switch result {
                case let .success(scene):
                    guard let goal = scene.goal else { return }
                    goal.components[CollisionComponent.self] = .none

                    let right = ShapeResource.generateCapsule(height: 3, radius: 0.13)
                                    .offsetBy(translation: [0,1.5,1.83])
                    let left = ShapeResource.generateCapsule(height: 3, radius: 0.13)
                                    .offsetBy(translation: [0,1.5,-1.83])
                    let upper = ShapeResource.generateCapsule(height: 4.1, radius: 0.12)
                                    .offsetBy(rotation: simd_quatf(angle: .pi/2, axis: [1,0,0]),
                                           translation: [0,2.8,0])
                    let net = ShapeResource.generateBox(width: 0.01, height: 3.3, depth: 3.9)
                                    .offsetBy(rotation: simd_quatf(angle: -.pi/4, axis: [0,0,1]),
                                           translation: [-1.3,1.4,0])
                    goal.components[CollisionComponent.self] =
                                    CollisionComponent(shapes: [right, left, upper, net])

                    self.arView.debugOptions = [.showPhysics]    
                    goal.scale /= 2
                
                    let anchor = AnchorEntity()
                    anchor.addChild(scene)
                    self.arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)

                case let .failure(error):
                    print("Failed to load scene: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Works flawlessly, Thank you!

May I ask, is it common to create colliders by using hardcoded values?

Comment: Sometimes you need to create a simple and effective collision shape, and using hardcoding for this is not a bad practice.

Comment: thank you! :) How can one choose the hardcoded values though? Is there a way to determine what would be the "perfect" hard-coded values for a model?

Comment: Use model bounding box' values as starting point – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72131489/realitykit-get-modelentity-size-as-simd3float/72133249#72133249