# Volumetric space clipping RealityView 3d model

Tags: realitykit, usdz, visionos, vision-pro

I am currently working on getting a 3d map of the US rendering in a volumetric window using RealityKit and RealityView, and no matter what I do, my model content is constantly clipped.

I am defining my window group as follows:

```swift
        WindowGroup {
            MapView()
        }
        .windowStyle(.volumetric)
        .defaultSize(Size3D(width: 2.7, height: 0.9, depth: 0.9), in: .meters)
```

And I am loading my usdz file in as such:

```swift
        RealityView { content in
            guard let usMap = try? await Entity(named: "us_map") else {
                return
            }

            content.add(usMap)
        }
```

What I end up with is the following:

[image: 3d US map]

I have also attempted to adjust the default size of the window, and it appears to have no effect on the outcome (i.e. I've set the width to 10, and I get the same result).

I have ruled out usdz file issues since if I transform the model and translate it to the right, Alaska comes into view, but then the right side of the model gets clipped.

Is there something that I can do to prevent this from happening?

It's also worth noting this happens on a real Apple Vision Pro device as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In visionOS 1.1, the max size of volumetric window is still 2x2x2 meters. Resize your model accordingly when you're placing it in RealityView, or apply autoscale inside [Model3D view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77307669/set-a-default-size-of-volumetric-window-to-fit-the-size-of-usdz-nodel/77339856#77339856).