Find the size of a 3D model in visionOS
I know that transform of a 3d model provides scale, rotation and translation info, but is there a way we can calculate the size of a 3d model in visionOS?

Getting model's size in visionOS
In RealityKit, there are 2 ways to find out what the model's size is. The first way can be found here. The second one is more convenient, since you simply tap on the model and the raycast(..) method returns you the required values. You can use system gestures' raycasting (my code represents this approach) or you can use ARKit's hand tracking raycast.
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {        
    @State var sizeOfModel: String = ""
    var material = UnlitMaterial()
    let building = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(width: 1.0,    // 1.0m
                                                 height: 3.5,    // 3.5m
                                                  depth: 1.0))   // 1.0m
    init() {
        material.color.texture = .init(try! .load(named: "texture"))
        building.model?.materials = [material]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { realityViewContent in
            building.components.set(InputTargetComponent())
            building.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
            
            let offset = building.visualBounds(relativeTo: nil).extents.y / 2
            building.position.y += offset
            building.position.z = -5.0
            realityViewContent.add(building)
        }
        .gesture(
            SpatialTapGesture()
                .targetedToAnyEntity()
                .onEnded {
                    // let location = $0.location
                    let scene = $0.entity.scene!
                                        
                    guard let castHit = scene.raycast(from: .zero,
                                                        to: [0, 0,-10]).first
                    else { return }
                    
                    let size = castHit.entity.visualBounds(relativeTo: nil)
                    let x = size.extents.x
                    let y = size.extents.y
                    let z = size.extents.z
                    
                    sizeOfModel = "Building's size is: \(x)m X \(y)m X \(z)m"
                    print(sizeOfModel)

                    // CollisionCastHit can also measure a distance for you
                    print("distance =", castHit.distance, "m")
                }
        )
    }
}



Hi @Andy Jazz: Why should we provide [0, 2, 10] and [0, 2, -10]?
guard let castHit = scene.raycast(from: [0, 2, 10],
to: [0, 2,-10]).first

Hi @NKD2007, in fact, even if you specify raycast(from: .zero, to: [0,0,-10]) the method will generally still work. The problem is that visionOS does not yet have an equivalent of ray(through:) instance method that is used in iOS to determine the position and direction of a ray through the given point in the 2D space (here our point is in 3D space), so at the moment in visionOS we can specify the direction in this way.

Hi @Andy Jazz: I tried as per this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72131489/realitykit-get-modelentity-size-as-simd3float/72133249#72133249 and tried using both ways (finding model entity as child to know the size and using visualBounds API), but found different result from the code. Check code in next comment.

let billboardSize = model.billboard.visualBounds(relativeTo: nil)
print("Billboard size (calucation 1) is (billboardSize.extents)")
let billboardSize2 = (model.billboard.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0] as! ModelEntity).model?.mesh.bounds
print("Billboard size (calucation 2) is (billboardSize2!.extents)")
output>>>>
Billboard size (calucation 1) is SIMD3(9.212055, 20.849077, 1.8132782)
Billboard size (calucation 2) is SIMD3(6.7261577, 7.809854, 6.7261577)

Hi @Andy Jazz. I also tried to get the visual bounds directly from $0.entity and it returned me correct value. So I'm not sure why we should use scene.raycast method. Can you explain?

Yep, you're absolutely right, you can use $0.entity to get a model's BB in this case, however, the object of CollisionCastHit gives you not only entity's sub-properties (bounding box, components, transform, etc) but also such important characteristics as position, normals and distance (in addition to the model's size). All this is possible thanks to good old raycasting.
